# Ubuntu Boot Issue: Hub 12-0:1-0: config failed: hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, configuration

I receive the title error message at boot, and it delays system startup by anywhere from 45-60 seconds.  Naturally, I'd like to resolve this delay.

I would greatly appreciate some tips on how I go about finding out what hardware device Hub 12-0:1-0 is?

System is:

- Distributor ID: Neon
- Description:    KDE neon 5.27
- Release:        22.04
- Codename:       jammy

Hardware is:

- MPG X670E CARBON WIFI (MS-7D70)
- AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16-Core Processor
- Bios: 1.72

Thank you

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Comment: Do you actually know what you're using?  You tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, then details show 22.04 in your question & you mention KDE Neon (*which only uses the LTS base & Qt5, KF5, KDE Plasma & more from later non-LTS releases thus isn't an LTS system only*)

Comment: Have you able to figure it out? I'm also getting the same error. With Ryzen 9 7900, MSI X670E ACE (MS-7D69) and BIOS Version: E7D69AMS.190. In my case, I'm using a ubuntu.

Comment: No - it's been ongoing, and I have not been able to figure it out